# NestJS cors error when do request from client on Next.js

Tags: node.js, next.js, https, cors, nestjs

Deploy my api project on vercel, but have cors error, when I do http request from a client on Next.js.

[image: Http request]

My Nest configuration is like in docs.

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
```

But I also tried diferent configurations

```
app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://api-filmgen-pearl.vercel.app'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true,
  });

//or
app.enableCors();

//or

  app.enableCors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: [/localhost:\d+$/, /\.vercel\.app$/, /\.herokuapp\.com$/],
    allowedHeaders: 'origin, content-type, accept, application/json',
  });
```

In Postmar, Swagger or local everything is ok.

**UPD**: My nest config

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true
  },

  i18n
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

**In React client app requests are also falling**

Comment: What does your `next-config.js` > `headers()` look like?

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu I don`t have headers() in next config file                                                                    ```/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true
  },

  i18n
}

module.exports = nextConfig```

Comment: @wesley I don`t have headers() in next config file, only post requests don`t working, and with react app client is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add options to vercel config

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/main.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "src/main.ts",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Heroku is a separate domain than Vercel which is also https, use the `secure: true` and `sameSite: 'none'` flags in your CORS config.

Next.js mentions in their [Caveats](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction#caveats) section that requests are by-default same-origin. They also provide a guide on how to customize route CORS behavior in the [CORS Request Helpers](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-cors) guide.